# Replace android Launcher activity animations

Tags: java, android, launcher

I'm creating my own Android Launcher.

The problem is:

- When I **launch** an activity, it slides left...
- When I **close** it, it slides right...
- **This is annoying and ugly!**

I've alread been able to remove the **launch** animation with:

```
Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
launch_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
launch_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

activity.startActivity(launch_intent);
```

My objective is to:

- Also remove the close application animation.
- Or change the launch/close default animations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's my impression that this is controlled by the application, or by the OS itself.  I don't know that it's possible to do this without writing your own distro of Android.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) could help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a look at the Android API demos, As was suggested you should use the "overridePendingTransition()" method, it sets the animation of the incoming activity and the animation of the outgoing activity.

The method shoud be added afer startActivity() or after finish():

```
    Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    launch_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));  
    activity.startActivity(launch_intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
```

The transitions are standard android animations, for example the zoom_enter will be something like that:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <scale android:fromXScale="2.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
           android:fromYScale="2.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
           android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

If you also want to set an animation when your activity is being closed, for example when user presses the back or home button, you should add the overridePendingTransition() to the onPause() method.
If you want to set an animation when your activity is being launched by some other application, add the overridePendingTransition() before the super.onCreate().

Comment: I'm developing a launcher, so in many applications lauched, I can't change their code. I want to disable the animations modifying only the launcher.

Comment: @inversus In that case add the overridePendingTransition() after the .startActivity() so you'll get the transition you want when an app is being opened from your launcher and the overridePendingTransition() before your super.onCreate() so when the launcher comes into view again the you'll also get the transition you want.

Comment: I also needed to add the overridePendingTransition() to the onResume on my launcher activity! The launcher is never destroyed so it only calls the onCreate at boot. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For displaying standard launcher animation you have to apply a specific theme for your main launcher activity. This theme should be (or should be inherited from) android:Theme.Wallpaper.
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper"`

For such theme Android Framework provides specific animations that you may see for standard Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I also think it is a irritating animation,so i also wanted to change it........and i found it as- it is default animation.........check this link........http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html
so i stopped searching for this issue ....